# Rigging & Complex Orders

Tags: shadowrun-sr5, drones

I have a player that oftenly asked his Drones to protect someone in autopilot or follow someone then he lost link (because of Noise) to come back to safehouse.

Is this possible ? Is an autosoft is required ?

Comment: Welcome to RPGSE. Please split this into two separate questions, because we only give focused answers here. (Edit this question to leave one topic, and create a second question for the other one.)

Comment: Hello, Thanks but I can't edit

Comment: @Morichika Your edit has been approved by me and will need a second approval, removing the second topic (drone size) from the question. Please create your second question separately while the approval is underway.

Comment: Hey @Morichika! It looks like you have accidentally created two accounts which is why you can't edit your own post. Please see [here](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts) for instructions on how to merge them again if you want to do  that!

Answer (score 3):

### Possibly.

Drones are not renowned for being particularly clever. If they are being directly controlled and that link is interrupted, the drone's pilot program will attempt to continue following its most recent orders. This pilot program is specific to the drone in question, and does not have to be purchased or run separately, as you would an autosoft. Depending on how vaguely defined "protecting" someone is, the GM may have the drone test to see if it can figure out what to do. From SR5 p. 269:

> When faced with something novel or unexpected, or a complicated command, a Pilot program must make a Device Rating x 2 Test against a threshold set by the gamemaster based on how confusing the situation is.

If the drone were to fail this test, it would either A) follow the target until a connection is re-established to the RCC, or B) hold position and attempt to re-connect to the RCC and request new orders.